# A field extension that is a finitely generated algebra is an algebraic extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Given a field $F$ and a field extension $K$ such that $K$ is a finitely generated $F$-algebra, show that $K$ is algebraic over $F$.

I think the result should follow by induction on the cardinality of a minimal generating set for $K$ as an $F$-algebra, but I haven't been able to proceed with that line of argument. I am guessing one needs to use some results about integral extensions, but I am not sure.

Comment: You can have a look at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski's_lemma.

Comment: @Watson Aha, didn't know it was a standard result. Thanks for the help.